# Change the object's namespace dynamically

Tags: c#, class, object, paypal

I use PayPal's service on Service References. As is known to have a PayPal SandBox environment.

I know a site is running on local or not.

My problem is that I want to dynamically change the namespace of the class by the environment (because the two classes have the same function). Eventually I want I do not have to change any code, but once automatically when the site is run by local the sandbox will and when he runs on the server is the real product will.

I want to switch between this:

```
using DynoPayPal.PayPal;
```

And this:

```
using DynoPayPal.SandBoxPayPal;
```

So that the object: `PaymentDetailsItemType` for example, will "be" `DynoPayPal.PayPal` in the first case, and `DynoPayPal.SandBoxPayPal` in the second case.

Comment: This screams Dependency Injection...

Comment: As @SimonWhitehead said, this really does seem like a prime candidate for DI. Do `SandBoxPayPal` and `PayPal` implement some common interface? Or do they at least implement the same methods?

Comment: Both have the same functions. The difference between them related to configuration (End Points)

Comment: Why would they be different types at all, rather than either obtaining or being given their configuration at execution time?

Comment: Seems like you should be able to just have a single service reference, and then change the connection string (web.confg? app.config) to point from sandbox to production on paypals side. (Just guessing, I'm not familiar with their API)

Comment: It sounds to me like you have created 2 different references... Surely you only needed one reference, and just change the URL?

Comment: I need both, sandebox for the local to tests, production to the server. I want I do not have to change anything in the code. PayPal's case is just an example. This can be a general question of change namespace object.

Comment: I suppose you could be super sneaky and on application load, detect if you're in localhost, if so change the endpoint of your service to the sandbox service. Not a great idea, because most people would look at the configuration and see it says one thing and not realize the code is dynamically changing it. Configuration files are for changing between environments and it sounds like that's exactly what you need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot change the namespace of a class.  That is not what they are there for, and it makes no sense whatsoever to do so.  But, as the comments to your question point out, what you are looking for is dependency injection.  Consider this:

```
public interface IPayPal
{
    void aMethod();
}


public class PayPal : IPayPal { /* ... */ }
public class SandboxPayPal : IPayPal { /* ... */ }
```

Then we can perhaps envisage a class that will give us the right one based on the environment:

```
public sealed class PayPalFactory
{
    public IPayPal Create()
    {
        if(EnvironmentIsLive) // replace this with a proper check!
            return new PayPal();
        else
            return new SandboxPayPal();
    }
}
```